# How to run a function only once in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

Sometimes I need to enter my external orders with code, I have a code which works fine BUT if I put it in the functions.php, it creates the order many time. I am looking for a way that the code would only create 1 order/be triggered only once

the code below works, but many time creates 5-20 of the same order

```
function create_vip_order() {
    global $woocommerce;

    $address = array(
        'first_name' => '',
        'last_name'  => '',
        'company'    => '',
        'email'      => '',
        'phone'      => '',
        'address_1'  => '',
        'address_2'  => '',
        'city'       => '',
        'state'      => '',
        'postcode'   => '',
        'country'    => ''
    );

    // Now we create the order
    $order = wc_create_order();

    // The add_product() function below is located in /plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract_wc_order.php
    $order->add_product( get_product( '2494' ), 1 ); // This is an existing SIMPLE product
    $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
    //
    $order->calculate_totals();
    $order->update_status("Processing", 'Imported order', TRUE);
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_vip_order' );
```

```
/**
 * Run code only once
 */
function my_run_only_once() {

    if ( get_option( 'my_run_only_once_01' ) != 'completed' ) {

        function create_vip_order() {
            global $woocommerce;

            $address = array(
                'first_name' => 'a',
                'last_name'  => 'a',
                'company'    => 'a',
                'email'      => 'a',
                'phone'      => 'a',
                'address_1'  => 'a',
                'address_2'  => 'a',
                'city'       => 'a',
                'state'      => 'fl',
                'postcode'   => '',
                'country'    => 'usa'
            );
            // Now we create the order
            $order = wc_create_order();
            // The add_product() function below is located in /plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract_wc_order.php
            $order->add_product( get_product( '3283' ), 3 ); 
            $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
            $order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );
            //
            $order->calculate_totals();
            $order->update_status("Processing", 'Imported order', TRUE);
        }
        add_action( 'init', 'create_vip_order' );

        update_option( 'my_run_only_once_01', 'completed' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_run_only_once' );
```

tried that but then nothing happened

How can i force that code to only create 1 order?

Comment: You should not be defining named functions within other named functions like that. What is calling `create_vip_order()` to begin with? Functions aren't executed unless they're called. If you're getting 5-20 of the same order, it's because you're calling that function as many times.

Comment: Hey, create_vip_order() is a code i found on stackoverflow, which allows you to enter a woocommerce order by pasting this code into de functions.php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2** - There are some mistakes and deprecated things in your code since WooCommerce 3. Try the following (commented):

```
// Function that create an order
function create_vip_order() {
    // Create a WC_Order instance object
    $order = wc_create_order();

    $order->add_product( wc_get_product( '3283' ), 3 ); // <== get_product() is deprecated and replaced by wc_get_product()

    $address = array(
        'first_name' => 'a',
        'last_name'  => 'a',
        'company'    => 'a',
        'address_1'  => 'a',
        'address_2'  => 'a',
        'city'       => 'a',
        'state'      => 'FL', // <== UPERCASE
        'postcode'   => '',
        'country'    => 'USA', // <== UPERCASE
        'email'      => 'abc@abc.com', // <== EMAIL REQUIRED
        'phone'      => '',
    );

    $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
    $order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );

    $order->calculate_totals();

    $order->update_status('processing', 'Imported order', true); // <== LOWERCASE for the WC status
}

// Triggered once
add_action( 'init', 'my_run_only_once' );
function my_run_only_once() {
    if ( did_action( 'init' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    if( ! get_option('run_create_vip_order_once') ) {

        create_vip_order(); // Run the function

        update_option( 'run_create_vip_order_once', true );
    }
}
```

Now the function that create the order will run only once as expected. Note that `global $woocommerce` is not needed anymore.

Comment: LoicTheAztec, i tried your code but i get Sorry, but your code causes a "Fatal error", so it is not applied!
Please, check the code and try again.

Comment: @mariepiercm Just updated the code twice … Tested and works without `global $woocommerce` and on backend no more duplicated order.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I wish you would answer his original question in the tile rather than just update his code